# Select all days in a week, when calendarweek is given

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

certainly something very simple, but for an application I would like to know how, if I know the calendar week, I can display the first to the last day of the week per row.

Currently, I am only shown the day in which content is present.

I would like to have 7 days displayed (as date, not necessarily with name) whether they are empty or not.

```
SELECT 
  MIN( TO_CHAR(LP_BELEGUNG.GEN_DATUM,'DD.MM.YYYY'))  AS GRD_ROW_ID    

, COUNT( DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN LP_BELEGUNG.ART = 1 THEN  LP_BELEGUNG.LP_BELEGUNG_ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) AS ANZAHL_ART_1

, COUNT( DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN LP_BELEGUNG.ART = 2 THEN  LP_BELEGUNG.LP_BELEGUNG_ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) AS ANZAHL_ART_2
  
, COUNT( DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN LP_BELEGUNG.ART = 3 THEN  LP_BELEGUNG.LP_BELEGUNG_ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) AS ANZAHL_ART_3          

, COUNT( DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN LP_BELEGUNG.ART = 99 THEN  LP_BELEGUNG.LP_BELEGUNG_ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) AS ANZAHL_ART_4

  FROM
     LP_BELEGUNG 
  WHERE 
     TO_CHAR(LP_BELEGUNG.GEN_DATUM, 'WW') = 37 --the calendar week
```

[image: Not like this]

Comment: Do you mean you want seven rows of data, with one row for each date in that week, some of which could have zeros in all four other columns? Or one row per week with 28 other columns, one per day per art value? And are you really only suppling a week number, not both year and week number? (And if so, what date do you show? Using `min()` like that isn't safe even for one year, never mind multiple years.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per day, for a week number in a given year, then you can generate all the dates in that week and use an outer join to look for matching rows in your table, if there are any.

Unfortunately Oracle doesn't supply a simple way to get a date from a week number, but based on how the WW element is defined you can start from the first day of the year and add the appropriate number of days to get the start of the week:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') + (7 * 37) - 7 from dual;
```

| TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY')+(7*37)-7 |
| --- |
| 10-SEP-22 |

... where 37 is the week number, and I've assumed you're looking at the current year (if not, use a fixed date like `date '2022-01-01'` instead of `trunc(sysdate)`).

You can then get all the days in that week with a hierarchical query:

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') + (7 * 37) + level - 8
from dual
connect by level <= 7;
```

| TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY')+(7*37)+LEVEL-8 |
| --- |
| 10-SEP-22 |
| 11-SEP-22 |
| 12-SEP-22 |
| 13-SEP-22 |
| 14-SEP-22 |
| 15-SEP-22 |
| 16-SEP-22 |

Then use those values in an inline view or CTE, and left-join to your table using a date range (to allow for non-midnight times but still allowing an index on that column to be used), grouping by the date:

```
with cte (dt) as (
  select trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') + (7 * 37) + level - 8
  from dual
  connect by level <= 7
)
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(cte.dt, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS GRD_ROW_ID

, COUNT( DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN LP_BELEGUNG.ART = 1 THEN  LP_BELEGUNG.LP_BELEGUNG_ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) AS ANZAHL_ART_1

, COUNT( DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN LP_BELEGUNG.ART = 2 THEN  LP_BELEGUNG.LP_BELEGUNG_ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) AS ANZAHL_ART_2
  
, COUNT( DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN LP_BELEGUNG.ART = 3 THEN  LP_BELEGUNG.LP_BELEGUNG_ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) AS ANZAHL_ART_3          

, COUNT( DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN LP_BELEGUNG.ART = 99 THEN  LP_BELEGUNG.LP_BELEGUNG_ID
    ELSE NULL
  END ) AS ANZAHL_ART_4

FROM
  cte
LEFT JOIN
  LP_BELEGUNG 
ON
  LP_BELEGUNG.GEN_DATUM >= cte.dt AND LP_BELEGUNG.GEN_DATUM < cte.dt + 1
GROUP BY
  cte.dt
ORDER BY
  cte.dt
```

With some sample data to mimic your original result, that gives:

| GRD_ROW_ID | ANZAHL_ART_1 | ANZAHL_ART_2 | ANZAHL_ART_3 | ANZAHL_ART_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.09.2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11.09.2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12.09.2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13.09.2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 14.09.2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 15.09.2022 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 16.09.2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/epkdiIKf)

Comment: Thank you Alex now I do not want to open a new question and think it is enough if I change the "with" part to 
- all days in month 
- all months of the year
- all weeks in the year
all weeks in the year. 
I changed sysdate with a fixed date and swap it for the year or month (01/01/2020- 02/01/2022 - 01/01/2021). Can you make me understand again how to change it?

Comment: @craverealize - I'm not sure what you mean. You can use a hierarchical query (or a recursive CTE) to generate all the days in a month, or a year, or any period - you just need to set the start date and end condition properly.

Comment: that is, if I have to be honest, still a little too high for me. I have from the application different tabs to select (calendar week, days in month, months in year, weeks in year) these are to show me the desired information

Answer (score 0):

Here is a set of dates counted and divided to days of the week using `to_char` and `pivot`.

```
select  *
from
(
select  dt
       ,to_char(dt, 'D') as dow
from    t
) t
pivot   (count(dt) for dow in('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')) p
```

| '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6xl3XJ2T)

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(GEN_DATUM),'DD.MM.YYYY')  AS GRD_ROW_ID,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 1
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 0
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_1_DAY1,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 1
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 1
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_1_DAY2,
       -- ...
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 1
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 6
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_1_DAY7,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 2
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 0
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_2_DAY1,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 2
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 1
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_2_DAY2,
       -- ...
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 2
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 6
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_2_DAY7,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 3
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 0
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_3_DAY1,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 3
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 1
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_3_DAY2,
       -- ...
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 3
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 6
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_3_DAY7,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 99
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 0
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_4_DAY1,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 99
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 1
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_4_DAY2,
       -- ...
       COUNT( DISTINCT
              CASE
              WHEN ART = 99
              AND  TRUNC(gen_datum) - TRUNC(gen_datum, 'WW')  = 6
              THEN LP_BELEGUNG_ID
              END
       ) AS ANZAHL_ART_4_DAY7
FROM   LP_BELEGUNG 
WHERE  TO_CHAR(GEN_DATUM, 'WW') = 37
```